# Loaded qml file from resource has not the same content as the referenced qml file?

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5

I'm using a resource module in my application running Python 3.6 with PyQt5 ( 5.8.1 ) on MacOs Sierra.

The resource configuration refers to a QML file and is configured like

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>qml/main.qml</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Generating the resource python module via call to

`pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc`

This QML is loaded into a QQuickView via

```
QQuickView.setSource(QUrl('qrc:qml/main.qml'))
```

When loading this QML from the resource via the compiled resources.py I see in my QQuickView that *some* QML is displayed - but it is not the latest content of the original QML file !? Even though I ran pyrcc right before executing the application !?

I verified that content resources.py changes between consecutive invocations of pyrcc5, following any content change of referenced QML file.

I even put a breakpoint inside the resources.py to double check that it gets loaded properly.

Why would my python program stick to old content of a Qt resource module ?

Comment: After further investigation I noticed that depending on how I compile the resource file ( invoking pyrcc executable ) the application either works normal or crashed or just misbehaved with respect to embedded resources.

Further analysis revealed that I had multiple pyrcc ( from different PyQt versions ) installed via virtual env and system wide.

Comment: When the current python virtual env was not initialized properly in current shell, I ended up using a pyrcc from a PyQt version that was different from the PyQt version I was using to run the application !

Once I doubled check that pyrcc was from the same PyQt version the problem(s) vanished...
I could have noticed that, because the generated resource python module contains a version description in a comment - which was alternating depending on which pyrcc (version) was invoked.